# BJam not compiling boost libraries with '-mt' tag when multi threading specified

Tags: boost, bjam, b2

I'm trying to compile boost v1.55 libraries for osx, with multi threading support. My user-config.jam configures the compiler as follows:

```
using clang : osx
: xcrun clang -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -stdlib=libstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9
;
```

And the command I run to build the libraries is as follows:

```
./b2 -a -j8 toolset=clang-osx link=static threading=multi --with-thread
```

However, the libraries generated are of the following format: libboost_.a, rather than libboost_-mt.a

Does anyone have any idea of why the '-mt' tag is omitted?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to enable the formatting I requested (where tags are added to the library name to indicate the configuration the library was compiled in), the appropriate *layout* parameter needs to be set in the build options. My build command should have looked like this:

```
./b2 -a -j8 toolset=clang-osx link=static threading=multi --layout=tagged --with-thread
```